# Ruby on Rails - Linking two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got an error while trying to access one single instance of an object in Ruby on Rails.
I think you should get my point when taking a look at my code.

I got my test-Model with the line

```
has_many :test_boards
```

and in the test_board-Model I got

```
belongs_to :test
```

Now I have a partial called _details.html.erb which gets rendered by show.html.erb and contains the following line:

```
<% @test_board = @test.test_board %>
```

Trying to load the site within my application fails now with the message

> NoMethodError in Tests#show
>   Showing C:/****/****/****/app/views/tests/_details.html.erb where line #270 raised:
>
> undefined method `test_board' for #< Test:0x769ccc8>
>   Trace of template inclusion: app/views/p_and_i/tests/show.html.erb

I hope, someone of you could help me, as I am on this point since days of researching for bugs. if you need some more details, I'll add them, of course.
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
<% @test_board = @test.test_boards %>
```

> undefined method `test_board' for #< Test:0x769ccc8>

You have `:has_many` association with `TestBoard` so the method rails generate for you to get all associated records is `test_boards`

Comment: Thank you.
Doing this, I got another problem:
In my test_boards/show.html.erb I have something like <%= test_board.title %>. As my @test_board variable contains multiple test_boards now, this fails.
Do you also have a solution for this? I think, it must be something like an array access, but Ruby solves this different, propably.

Comment: Yes you will have to loop over `@test_board` with `@test_board.each do |test_board|`

Comment: and for redability you should change variable name to `@test_boards`

Answer (score 2):

Since the relation defined is of one to many  that means a single test can have multiple test_boards

So you should use @test.test_boards instead of @test.test_board

if you try calling @test.test_board it takes it as a one to one relation i.e a test has a single  test board

For further knowledge please go through the rails guide

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1):

Test has_many test_boards

So you have to write:

```
 @test_board = @test.test_boards
```

Answer (score 0):

The association shows that `test` has many `test_boards`. So you can reference it as `test_boards` i.e plural only.

So you can achieve the above with

```
<% @test_board = @test.test_boards %>
```

Although this works, there are some good practises you should follow.

- As `@test.test_boards` will give a collection the variable name should also be plural. So you can use `@test_boards = @test.test_boards` instead
- Moreover you should define instance variables in controller actions. So you can move this `@test_boards = @test.test_boards` to your TestsController.